# python urllib2 stuck while save file

Tags: python, urllib2

i need to download some PDF from internet and save it with my python program so i try to find how to do it in internet and i got urllib2.urlopen with write code like this my code:

```
resp = urllib2.urlopen(pdf)

with open("/home/mysaveFile/myDownloadedPdf_{}.pdf".format(number), 'wb') as f:
f.write(resp.read())
```

but somtimes my code hang/stuck in with open f.write can someone tell why is that happen? and how to solve this?